# Should I pay off zero interest debt early?

Tags: interest-rate, debt, debt-reduction, emergency-fund

My cash reserves are around $11k, including an emergency fund of about a month and a half, and I budget rigorously.  The only debt I have is $7k at zero interest, paid at $300/month, and it's from a family member who would almost certainly defer payments if something catastrophic happened. (BTW, our family has successfully made and paid tens of thousand of dollars of inter-member debt for many years, and the bankers and lenders vary over time.)

I happen to be in a free Dave Ramsey class, and a question came up.  Should I pay off the zero interest debt before finishing my emergency fund?  If so, why?  My inclination is to finish accumulating my emergency fund first.  The only substantive argument I can see to pay early is an emotional one:  it's appealing and secure to have zero debt. Paying it off early will actually cost me money, because inflation is decreasing the value of the debt over time.  My job is extremely stable, and also it's a rotating 12 month contract where I doubt they ever break the contract.

P.S.  I should be honest and admit I'm currently throwing away some 401k match;  my employer matches an incredible 9% 1-for-1 but I can only afford 8% while I'm getting on my feet.  I've calculated that 8.5% is sufficient for my retirement.

Comment: 8.5% originally struck me as a bit low to be sufficient for retirement, but then I remembered that you are getting that matched, so assuming you stay at the company long enough to be fully vested, your actual savings rate is 17%, which is flipping fantastic :). Just thought I would point out that for those who don't have such a great match, 8.5% is not always enough to save for retirement, depending on one's income of course.

Comment: Also, may I ask in what sector you work (and in what country - I assume USA)?

Comment: My sector is education, and it is indeed in the USA.  My guess is the match is so high because some employees have grossly undersaved so the organization is trying to help them out.  While we're being precise, it's actually a 403b, which is a similar animal to a 401k.

Comment: I decided to continue building my cushion and increase my retirement contribution to max out the match.  Almost 18 months later and post-marriage I still believe that was the correct decision. I still like Dave Ramsey.

Comment: This is a morale vs economics question. Seeing you choose to ask this in money and not in interpersonal shows you already answered it for yourself.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First I must say that I'm not a Ramsey fan. Sometimes loans will make your financial situation significantly better. Especially if its a 0% loan. Generally, I do think that leveraging has its place, its the **ab**-use of loans what causes problems, not the use.

Re your question - you're right in trying to first build up an emergency fund. You should have enough in it to be able to pay for yourself for at least half a year of unemployment or zero income. You only have one month.

Your family member gave you money for free, which is admirable, but I'm sure there's a limit to everyone's generosity and he might not give it to you for free again, once you pay it off. Thus, you should be able to handle your future troubles on your own, and emergency fund is a crucial part of this.

Pay as agreed, try not to be late, and you'll pay the loan off within 3 years. If you accumulate enough emergency fund, and you still have some extra left - pay some extra on the loan in order to pay it off early.

Do make sure you take full advantage of the employer's 401k match. This has, IMHO, much higher priority than paying off the 0% loan early.

Comment: +1 on everything. Except I would build the emergency fund slower in order to take advantage of the 401K matching, continuing to pay the loan as agreed. After the money is in 401K if you are ever in a true emergency you could withdraw or take a loan against it.

Comment: What geo said. I'd not skip a match to put cash aside at zero interest.

Comment: Note - littleadv did say to grab the full match, so it's not an exception, just extra agreement.....

Comment: It´s not exactly zero interest. It´s just that the interest is at the expense of others in the form of opportunity-costs. I don´t agree with the family/generosity part of the answer. I would presume paying back early would set you up for even more generosity as you show you don´t take advantage of it.

Answer (score 6):

I´d like to offer another perspective, neglected in the other Answers.

1. The loaned money is not zero-interest. It will cost your family-member some opportunity-cost to lend it to you vs investing it elsewhere. You have to realize that this part, the interest of the loan, is a gift from this person.
2. I don´t know the condition under which the loan came to be, but it can make sense to build a history of trust. Having *good credit* inside your family can be a worth of its own, and apparently also serves as a kind of emergency fund until you build your own. You will presumably be more likely to get another family loan if you need it, when you show you don´t take advantage of it.

I think the best course of action is to play with open cards and discuss the financial options with your respective family member. If they are old-fashioned and would keep the money in a savings-account anyways, it will not make much of a difference. If they are actively managing their assets, the might appreciate your early payback. I any event you will gain peace-of-mind and trust from your *investor*.

Answer (score -3):

First, I must say I am a Ramsey fan.

Here's the thing, the borrower is slave to the lender, so if you eat Thanksgiving dinner with your generous relative next week, the food will taste different.  Before I was a Dave fan, I borrowed money from my cousin once, and that debt was always hanging over my head.  At times, it made hanging out awkward since I had money to 'go out' but not money to 'pay back.'  It felt great once I paid him off, but the awkwardness was never cool.

I'm sure some will disagree (Dave wouldn't), but if you **TEMPORARILY** stop your 8% contribution, and combine that with your current margin, you could pay off the debt from your cash flow and complete your emergency fund.  Since you said that $11k is 1.5 month's expenses, you would essentially need to double that for a three-month fund or quadruple it for a six month fund.  I know $300 may not seem like a lot, but since I value family over money, I would pay that off today out of the $11k and then replenish and fill the emergency fund.

Also, your expenses will have dropped by $300/mo., so it will take less money to get to three or six month's expenses.  Once that's complete, get your full 8% contribution.

FYI: I consider margin to be the difference between your income and your outgo.

Comment: That would make 0% loan to become 8% loan (much more in fact, because 8% is of the salary). Isn't it a waste? I'm sure Ramsey would disagree with you.

Comment: I highly doubt it.  Ramsey is pretty consistent.  My guess is Dave would say to payoff the debt, stop 401(k) contribution until the emergency fund is completed.  When that's done, resume 401(k) contribution.

Comment: then I'm even less fan of him. That is a ridiculous proposal that would definitely harm the OP.

Comment: because owing money to family is somehow harmless?

Comment: Why would it not be harmless? As long as you keep your obligations, shouldn't be any problem. Also, the "bad feeling" of indebtedness to your uncle is IMHO much better than the bad feeling of not having food to eat when you're old.

Comment: I think we will have to agree to disagree on this concept. When you owe someone you have a relationship with (familial or otherwise), and you owe them money, then you allow them to have a say, or at the very least - an opinion, about what you do with your money.  How would you feel if someone owed you $7k, and then you had an emergency, or other situation, where you needed that money?  What if they missed a payment, but had the new iPad, or other luxury item?

If you aren't in debt, then you have money to invest and save so that you will have food to eat when you're old.

Comment: I actually don't need to guess how would I feel. Been there, done that, and doing it still. I wouldn't lend money that would otherwise be my emergency fund, and I would call on defaults, but other than that, and as I said to the OP, as long as they pay as agreed, I don't care how many iPads they can afford. If someone gives you money for free, it does show a certain level of trust and affection to begin with. And as I said - the OP shouldn't abuse it, and pay as agreed. But NOT on the account of his own future, unless he would otherwise default.

Comment: I would prefer to not have any debts hanging over my head.  Period, point blank.  Life is less messy for me that way.  Less overhead, less drama.

Comment: While understandable, this is not rational. That's why I'm not a Ramsey fan - the claim that you should never have debt or should do anything to get rid of debt, even if it hurts you in the long term, is irrational.

Comment: I'm curious to why you think people should have debt then?  I only ask because before I became a Ramsey fan, I didn't like debt, but was no acutely against it as I am now.  There was information that didn't have then that I have now that changed my mind.

Comment: if the cost of debt is less than a benefit, then why not have debt? I don't mind carrying 0-APR balance on my credit card, or taking mortgage at the interest rate less than inflation, and see no reason to forgo such opportunities. In this case (of the OP), the debt doesn't cost anything, but your solution actually makes it significantly more expensive than it could have been. You're suggesting to pay enormous amounts of money for no benefit.

Comment: I understand Waddler's perspective.  I have indeed loaned out money and been surprised when the recipient had something expensive I didn't (OTOH, I'm also quite frugal), but I got over it quickly.  In my current case my cushion exceeds my debt, so if my relative wanted the full balance tomorrow he'd have it the day after.  So I don't have to worry too much when I'm eating with him; indeed I don't think about it at all.

Comment: This advice would effectively cost the OP 100%. i.e. Every dollar put anywhere else could have been an instant $2 in the 401(k). By all means, pay off debt, even the zero rate, if you wish, but consider the cost of leaving free money behind. A 21 year old who maximizes his 401(k) for the first 5 years will be ahead of those that start at 26 even if the 21 year old stops depositing. Long term growth is tough to recover. It's these horrific bits of advice from The David that made me lose any interest in anything he says.

Comment: It's the missing out on something like the company match that lights the fire to get out of debt sooner.  I tried paying off debt while also contributing to my 401(k), sure it grew, but my debts weren't going away.

Comment: no one has mentioned risk as a reason to get rid of debt. When you have debt and you lose your source of income, you still have to pay the debt, but now you don't have a source of income. What if the 0% debt is called - meaning the person that loaned the money wants the principle back immediately?.... Debt makes future risk part of the calculation. It's not worth a few extra bucks to takes chances.

Comment: @rocketman You're absolutely right!  I should have been more explicit about the risk factor of debt.

Comment: This is essentially an emotional argument. It's entirely possible that the lender and the borrower aren't weird about the loan. The OP says as much.

Comment: But sometimes family and friends are weird about loans, so it is worth mentioning. I know I won't loan to or borrow from my family. They're horrible about that kind of stuff.

Comment: This might be good advice on [Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/), but it is terrible advice on [Personal Finance & Money](https://money.stackexchange.com).